# Resultados diferentes fazendo o que eu acho que é a mesma coisa ( mongoose js )

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho esse código

```
var questionscount = await Question.find({
        $or: [
            { titulo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } },
            { corpo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } }
        ]
    }).count()
console.log(questionscount)
```

isso functiona normalmente.

Mas porque quando eu faço:

```
var questions = await Question.find({
        $or: [
            { titulo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } },
            { corpo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } }
        ]
    }) 
console.log(questions.count())
```

isso dá erro

> questions.count is not a function

Comment: O que `Question.find` retorna? Um objeto?

Answer (score 1):

O operador `await` invoca o método `then` e te retorna o argumento que iria no *callback*. Ele é açúcar semântico para transformar código funcional em código imperativo.

O equivalente do primeiro código sem `await` seria:

```
Question
    .find({
        $or: [
            { titulo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } },
            { corpo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } }
        ]
    })
    .count()
    .then(questionscount => {
        console.log(questionscount);
    });
```

Enquanto do segundo seria:

```
Question
    .find({
        $or: [
            { titulo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } },
            { corpo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } }
        ]
    })
    .then(questions => {
        console.log(questions.count());
    });
```

Como você pode ver, eles não são equivalentes. No primeiro código você cria a sua query com duas *pipelines* (`find` e `count`), enquanto na segunda você monta a query apenas com `find`, e manda executa-la, e depois invoca `count` no resultado, mas o resultado não tem esse método, o método pertence a query, não ao resultado.

O equivalente seria fazer:

```
var questionsQuery = Question.find({
    $or: [
        { titulo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } },
        { corpo: { $regex: termo, $options: 'i' } }
    ]
});
var questionsCount = await questionsQuery.count();
console.log(questionsCount);
```

Comment: Eu copiei exatamente o mesmo código que você botou aqui para ver se dava certo, e retornou TypeError , questions.count is not a function .

Comment: @Rafa0712, leia com atenção, o segundo exemplo que eu postei aqui é para dar erro de propósito, assim como o código que você postou dá erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando 'await', isso quer dizer que seu código será executado de forma assíncrona, ou seja, o restante do código será executado enquanto aguarda o retorno da chamada.

Quando você utiliza:

```
console.log(questions.count())
```

Gera um erro porque a chamada assíncrona ainda não retornou o resultado, então o objeto 'questions' ainda está vazio, portanto a função 'count()' ainda não existe nele.

No seu primeiro exemplo o código funciona, porque a função 'count()' está inclusa na chamada assíncrona, e portanto só será executada quando o objeto for efetivamente retornado pela query.